# Let $p,q$ be odd primes such that $p-q=4a.$ Prove that $\Bigg(\dfrac{a}{p}\Bigg)=\Bigg(\dfrac{a}{q}\Bigg).$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, legendre-symbol

Let $p,q$ be odd primes such that $p-q=4a.$ Prove that $\Bigg(\dfrac{a}{p}\Bigg)=\Bigg(\dfrac{a}{q}\Bigg).$

Could anyone advise on how to prove the equality? Hints will suffice, thank you.

Comment: First hint: note that $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{2}{p}\right)^2\left(\frac{a}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{4}{p}\right)\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)= \left(\frac{4a}{p}\right).$

Comment: Quadratic reciprocity and a little bit of knowledge of how to manipulate Legendre symbols will suffice for the rest.

Comment: Hint: $p$ and $q$ both leave the same remainder on division by $4a$.

Comment: sorry, overread that there was the tag legendre symbol.

Comment: @Enkidu Ah, now your comments make much more sense! I was really puzzled by your reasoning there. Simple misunderstanding then.

Comment: @SamStreeter Thanks for hints. We can deduce that $\Big(\frac{a}{q}\Big)=\Big(\frac{4a}{q}\Big).$

Comment: @AlexyVincenzo So can you solve the problem now?

Comment: Yes, I can solve it now. Thank you very much:)

Answer (score 3):

$\Big(\dfrac{a}{p}\Big)= \Big(\dfrac{4a}{p}\Big)=\Big(\dfrac{p-q}{p}\Big)=\Big(\dfrac{-q}{p}\Big) =\Big(\dfrac{-1}{p}\Big)\Big(\dfrac{q}{p}\Big)=(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\Big(\dfrac{q}{p}\Big)$

$\Big(\dfrac{a}{q}\Big)= \Big(\dfrac{p}{q}\Big)=(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2} \cdot\frac{q-1}{2}}\Big(\dfrac{q}{p}\Big).$

If $\dfrac{p-1}{2}$ is even, then we are done.  If $\dfrac{p-1}{2}$ is odd, then $p \equiv 3  \ (\text{mod} \ 4) \implies q+4a \equiv 3  \ (\text{mod} \ 4) \implies q-1 \equiv 2 \ (\text{mod} \ 4) \implies \dfrac{q-1}{2}$ is odd.